# Do projectors work from the front and the rear?

Tags: projector

Or do you have to purchase one specific to your use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do rear projection it would have to be capable of flipping the image horizontally. I think it's fairly standards, but check what control you have over the image just to be sure.

For example, I've seen projectors mounted upside down from the ceiling with the controls facing downwards project an "upright" image - i.e. one rotated 180<sup>o</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

Usually they have a setting to flip the projection so that you can use it from behind or in front - I've never used one without that setting.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, projectors have a flip setting to allow them to be used from either side. Most  graphics cards also offer this feature for any display output, so even if your projector doesn't support it, your gpu probably will.